# Linux for loop for 2 inputs and 4 outputs

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, awk

I need help to write a `for` loop.

`Input:` file01_R1.fastq, file01_R2.fastq. I have 100 files e.g., file02_R1.fastq, file02_R2.fastq and so on.

`Output:` file01_R1_PE.fastq, file01_R1_SE.fastq, file01_R2_PE.fastq, file01_R2_SE.fastq

I need to write a for loop so that I can run an executable for all 100 files. Any help please!

Comment: If the fact that this question is related to `Trimmomatic tool for quality trimming of paired end fastq` is relevant, you're probably asking in the wrong forum as I suspect there's not too many `Trimmomatic` experts reading this. If it's not relevant, get rid of that info from the question.  Edit your question to just give us a relevant description along with testable input and output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: so you only need help with the `for` loop? If not, please edit your question to include small examples for R1 and R2 and the expected output from that data. Maybe include 1 unmatching record and indicate what should happen to that.  At least add a link to Trimmomatic documentation. As is the question is very vague. Good luck!

Comment: Dear @Ed Morton, Thank a lot for your comment. I only need help in `for` loop. I have edited the question.

Comment: OK, I've provided the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Store 'R1.fastq' files in an array and run loop for all 'R2.fastq' files

```
R1.fastq=*_R1.fastq
for R2.fastq in *_R2.fastq
i=0
do command ${R1.fastq[$((i++))]} $R2.fastq
done
```

Name the output files as required by `Trimmomatic`

Answer (score 3):

I assume that given the file

```
file01_R1.fastq
```

you want to run:

```
Trimmomatic file01_R1.fastq file01_R2.fastq -o file01_R1_PE.fastq file01_R1_SE.fastq file01_R2_PE.fastq file01_R2_SE.fastq
```

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel Trimmomatic {} {= s/_R1/_R2/ =} -o {= s/_R1/_R1_PE/ =} {= s/_R1/_R1_SE/ =} {= s/_R1/_R2_PE/ =} {= s/_R1/_R2_SE/ =} ::: *_R1.fastq
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes it easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: As usual, beautiful answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in *
do
    some_command_that_does_something_unspecified "$file"
done
```

Comment: I dont think it will work for my case. My input is two files with same prefix and output 4 files with the same prefix. Please see my input and output file name for clarification. Thanks!

Comment: You have provided absolutely nothing that would mean that this solution is not what you want.